TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'JSX'. - What is equivalent of `JSX.IntrinsicElements`?
I have crafted a library for next.js themes. Recently, I found this error here.
The latest version of Typescript 5.7.2 complains - TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'JSX'. What is the equivalent of JSX.IntrinsicElements that can be used to set the type of HTML Tags in React components?

You can use React.JSX.IntrinsicElements

It turns out that we need to now use keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap in place of keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements.
HTMLElementTagNameMap is available in lib.dom.d.ts
The full definition of the interface is as follows
interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    "a": HTMLAnchorElement;
    "abbr": HTMLElement;
    "address": HTMLElement;
    "area": HTMLAreaElement;
    "article": HTMLElement;
    "aside": HTMLElement;
    "audio": HTMLAudioElement;
    "b": HTMLElement;
    "base": HTMLBaseElement;
    "bdi": HTMLElement;
    "bdo": HTMLElement;
    "blockquote": HTMLQuoteElement;
    "body": HTMLBodyElement;
    "br": HTMLBRElement;
    "button": HTMLButtonElement;
    "canvas": HTMLCanvasElement;
    "caption": HTMLTableCaptionElement;
    "cite": HTMLElement;
    "code": HTMLElement;
    "col": HTMLTableColElement;
    "colgroup": HTMLTableColElement;
    "data": HTMLDataElement;
    "datalist": HTMLDataListElement;
    "dd": HTMLElement;
    "del": HTMLModElement;
    "details": HTMLDetailsElement;
    "dfn": HTMLElement;
    "dialog": HTMLDialogElement;
    "div": HTMLDivElement;
    "dl": HTMLDListElement;
    "dt": HTMLElement;
    "em": HTMLElement;
    "embed": HTMLEmbedElement;
    "fieldset": HTMLFieldSetElement;
    "figcaption": HTMLElement;
    "figure": HTMLElement;
    "footer": HTMLElement;
    "form": HTMLFormElement;
    "h1": HTMLHeadingElement;
    "h2": HTMLHeadingElement;
    "h3": HTMLHeadingElement;
    "h4": HTMLHeadingElement;
    "h5": HTMLHeadingElement;
    "h6": HTMLHeadingElement;
    "head": HTMLHeadElement;
    "header": HTMLElement;
    "hgroup": HTMLElement;
    "hr": HTMLHRElement;
    "html": HTMLHtmlElement;
    "i": HTMLElement;
    "iframe": HTMLIFrameElement;
    "img": HTMLImageElement;
    "input": HTMLInputElement;
    "ins": HTMLModElement;
    "kbd": HTMLElement;
    "label": HTMLLabelElement;
    "legend": HTMLLegendElement;
    "li": HTMLLIElement;
    "link": HTMLLinkElement;
    "main": HTMLElement;
    "map": HTMLMapElement;
    "mark": HTMLElement;
    "menu": HTMLMenuElement;
    "meta": HTMLMetaElement;
    "meter": HTMLMeterElement;
    "nav": HTMLElement;
    "noscript": HTMLElement;
    "object": HTMLObjectElement;
    "ol": HTMLOListElement;
    "optgroup": HTMLOptGroupElement;
    "option": HTMLOptionElement;
    "output": HTMLOutputElement;
    "p": HTMLParagraphElement;
    "picture": HTMLPictureElement;
    "pre": HTMLPreElement;
    "progress": HTMLProgressElement;
    "q": HTMLQuoteElement;
    "rp": HTMLElement;
    "rt": HTMLElement;
    "ruby": HTMLElement;
    "s": HTMLElement;
    "samp": HTMLElement;
    "script": HTMLScriptElement;
    "search": HTMLElement;
    "section": HTMLElement;
    "select": HTMLSelectElement;
    "slot": HTMLSlotElement;
    "small": HTMLElement;
    "source": HTMLSourceElement;
    "span": HTMLSpanElement;
    "strong": HTMLElement;
    "style": HTMLStyleElement;
    "sub": HTMLElement;
    "summary": HTMLElement;
    "sup": HTMLElement;
    "table": HTMLTableElement;
    "tbody": HTMLTableSectionElement;
    "td": HTMLTableCellElement;
    "template": HTMLTemplateElement;
    "textarea": HTMLTextAreaElement;
    "tfoot": HTMLTableSectionElement;
    "th": HTMLTableCellElement;
    "thead": HTMLTableSectionElement;
    "time": HTMLTimeElement;
    "title": HTMLTitleElement;
    "tr": HTMLTableRowElement;
    "track": HTMLTrackElement;
    "u": HTMLElement;
    "ul": HTMLUListElement;
    "var": HTMLElement;
    "video": HTMLVideoElement;
    "wbr": HTMLElement;
}


Another alternative is React.ReactHTML
